# Get a MPS file using NEOS/GAMS web interface

Tags: modeling, neos, gams

I'm trying to use Neos/GAMS to solve an optimization problem. I will need to get a MPS file from the model. With using GAMS IDE it is easy to use an option file to get it but, it needs a licence file for large models.

My question is, is there any way to get an MPS file using the Neos/GAMS web interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a MPS file using GAMS, you have two options as follows:

1. Your first option is to use the [CONVERT](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/S_CONVERT.html) solver. AFAIK, this solver is not available on NEOS Server (see [here](https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/index.html) for a list of available solvers).
2. Your second option is to use the solver-specific options to create MPS files. For example, CPLEX has a *writemps* option, which allows you to generate a MPS file in CPLEX format. Again, NEOS Server does not allow any output file other than solution GDX and log files. Hence, I don't think you can use this option either.

I think you have to option to overcome this situation as follows:

1. First, you might find some open-source solver that supports generating MPS files as its output. Perhaps, COIN-OR can do this, but I'm not familiar with it. Others might provide more information.
2. The second option is to write a computer code to write MPS files for your specific problem. There are various sources on the web that describe the MPS file structure. One example is available from [here](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.0/mps-format.htm).

Comment: thanks so much for the detailed explanation